# How do I make json file in src/main/resources/ accessable when spring application is hosted in a docker container?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read a json file that is located under src/main/resources, this works just fine locally but after having built docker-image the same code reports "IOException - File not found" when it's deployed.

Here is the code attempting to load in the class:

```
@Component
public class KontorAdmin {
    List<KontorInfo> kontorer;

    String filePath = "./src/main/resources/kontortoggle.json";

    public KontorAdmin() throws IOException {
        initKontor();
    }
    
    public void initKontor() throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        KontorWrapper kontorWrapper = objectMapper.readValue(file, KontorWrapper.class);
        this.kontorer = kontorWrapper.getKontorer();
    }
```

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
VOLUME /tmp

ADD target/rek-service.jar rek-service.jar
EXPOSE 80:80

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","rek-service.jar"]
```

I'm thinking I could ADD the file to docker, but how do I then make it pass unit tests locally which expects a different path to file?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the resource file is in your classpath.

You should try reading like this,

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:kontortoggle.json");
```

or

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("kontortoggle.json").getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is your file access. When building the jar, your json file is moved as part of the jar file. Therefor you never may find this file by a simple file access by its name. Your resource json file is part of the rek-service.jar file. You have multiple opportunities to access this file.

In your use case you are using an fasterxml object mapper. This can be used with files or streams. I would suggest to use a stream by this code:

```java
@Component
public class KontorAdmin {
    List<KontorInfo> kontorer;


    public KontorAdmin() throws IOException {
        initKontor();
    }
    
    public void initKontor() throws IOException {
         InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("kontortoggle.json");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        KontorWrapper kontorWrapper = objectMapper.readValue(is, KontorWrapper.class);
        this.kontorer = kontorWrapper.getKontorer();
    }
```

But by the @Component annotation I suspect, that you are using spring. With Spring this is much easier to get the InputStream or File from class path. Then you should take a look at the ClassPathResource or the ResourceUtils. The ResourceUtils seems to be for internal use by JavaDoc, but anyone is using them in Spring.

new ClassPathResource("data/employees.dat", this.getClass().getClassLoader());

ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:kontortoggle.json");

```java
@Component
public class KontorAdmin {
    List<KontorInfo> kontorer;


    public KontorAdmin() throws IOException {
        initKontor();
    }
    
    public void initKontor() throws IOException {
        

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        KontorWrapper kontorWrapper = objectMapper.readValue(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:kontortoggle.json"), KontorWrapper.class);
        this.kontorer = kontorWrapper.getKontorer();
    }
```